# What should be done with these dupes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

- [How do I turn a String into a InputStreamReader in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247161/1768232)

  - Score: 139, Views: 101k, Answers: 6, Posted: October 2008, CW: No
- [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/782178/1768232)

  - Score: 288, Views: 195k, Answers: 3, Posted: April 2009, CW: Yes

Someone voted to close the second one as a duplicate of the first today. They are very, very blatant dupes, but I don't know which should be master, or if they should be merged, or what.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't know Java, but typically, I would say the question with the best answer should be the "master"

Answer (score -1):

Firstly thank you for meta to share my idea's and opinions..

As i gone through the two questions,  [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java) is owned by community wiki. So it is better to keep this question in SOF.

and one fair thing you missed in the question, such as [How do I turn a String into a Stream in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247161/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-stream-in-java) is active "7 months ago" and [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782178/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-inputstream-in-java) is active "15 days ago"

if there is any identical answers which helps to the user mostly means you merge the both questions is best choice !!

Thanks.